# LINQ sorting special characters first?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

It looks like special characters are not being regarded when sorting with LINQ and I didn't expect it to. Anyway, I need to sort special characters so they appear first in a list. Any ideas? I know I can do something like: [Use LINQ for arbitrary sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921107/use-linq-for-arbitrary-sorting), but how do I allow the sort to extend pass the special characters:

Example List:

- "Test"
- Test

Daniel

Comment: Which LINQ? LINQ-to-Objects? LINQ-to-SQL? DbLinq? EF? ADO.NET Data Services? It matters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the less-well-known features of .Net 3.5 is that you can substitue a lambda for an IComparer. This is handy for cases like this where you want a one-off sort. If this **isn't** a one-off, you're probably better off with a custom IComparer class.  Here's how you'd do this brute force style:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    if(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x[0])){
        if(!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y[0])){
            // x is a letter/digit and y is not, override regular CompareTo
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y[0]))
    {
        // y is a letter/digit and x is not, override regular CompareTo
        return 1;
    }
    return x.CompareTo(y);
});
```

Comment: The overload of List<T>.Sort() that accepts a Comparer<T> delegate has been around since .NET 2.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28VS.80%29.aspx This would not work for methods like OrderBy that only accept an IComparer<T>.

Comment: I applied this to the OrderBy method.

Answer (score 3):

System.Linq.Enumerable provides overloads of [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) and ThenBy that accept a comparer that implements [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx). You would just need to write your own comparer (one method) that defines how you want the strings to be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

`qry = qry.OrderBy(q => q.VALUE.Replace("-","aaa"));`

This worked for me.It is simple.